# Replace Text in sub-string in column 1 with string in column 2

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

Im writing some script in T-SQL and managed to get a table in this format

```
ID  | Column 1            | Column 2
1   | 451151,abcabc,uibc  | abcabc
```

Id basically like to replace any instances of the string in column 2 that appear anywhere in column 1 with the string in column 2 but enclosed in speech marks.

So the output would look like

```
ID  | Column 1              | Column 2
1   | 451151,"abcabc",uibc  | abcabc
```

Comment: Hint: You need Update and replace to accomplish your job.

Comment: If you have `451151,abcabc,uibc` in col1 and `abc` in col2 - do you want to enclose both `abc` together or separate or neither?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but could you give this a try ?

```
UPDATE mytable SET column1 = REPLACE(column1,column2,'"' + column2 + "'")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to search and replace the fullword between commas try something like this (else `Replce(column1, column2)` function would be enough):

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b83ff/1)**:

```
update yourTable
set column1 = substring(       
        replace(',' + column1 + ',', ',' + column2 + ',', ',"' + column2 + '",'),
        2,len(column1)+2 );
where column2 is not null
```

Results:

```
| ID |              COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
|----|----------------------|---------|
|  1 | 451151,"abcabc",uibc |  abcabc |
|  2 |    123456,wxyz,mnop, |      yz | --NOTE: yz not replaced as it is not a full word between commas
```